# Where is the "Experiments" section in the Google Analytics web interface?

Tags: google-analytics, ab-testing

I am trying to configure A/B testing experiments in Google Analytics. I am reading https://developers.google.com/analytics/solutions/experiments-client-side and they explain that it is possible to "configure the experiment using the Google Analytics web interface". Where exactly within the Google Analytics web interface can I find the "Experiments" section to start configuring A/B testing experiments? I visited https://analytics.google.com/analytics/web/ and I do not see it there. Thank you.

Edit: The answer is at https://developers.google.com/analytics/solutions/experiments-client-side. I just had to keep reading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind, the answer is at https://developers.google.com/analytics/solutions/experiments-client-side.

Edit: Under the "BEHAVIOR" category, the "Experiments" sections can be found:

[image]